# Discord.js v14 - How to get selectmenu interaction in another class

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need to get the application that I selected in this selectmenu:

```
const { SquareCloudAPI } = require('@squarecloud/api');
const { squareToken } = require('../../config');

const api = new SquareCloudAPI(squareToken);

module.exports = {
    customId: 'square-apps',
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ExtendedClient} client 
     * @param {StringSelectMenuInteraction} int
     */
    run: async (client, int) => {
        try {

            const selectedAppId = int.values[0];

            const user = await api.users.get();
            const app = await api.applications.get(selectedAppId);
            const status = await app.getStatus();

            const tag = user.applications.get(selectedAppId).tag;
            const botId = user.applications.get(selectedAppId).id;
            const botAvatar = user.applications.get(selectedAppId).avatar;

            const statusPt = status.status === 'running' ? 'Ligado' : 'Desligado';
            const networkUsage = status.usage.network;

            int.reply({
                embeds: 
                [{
                    author: {
                        name: `${tag} [${botId}]`,
                        icon_url: botAvatar
                    },
                    description: `** Informações da aplicação:**\n
                    > **CPU:** ${status.usage.cpu} 
                    > **Ram:** ${status.usage.cpu}
                    > **Disco:** ${status.usage.storage}
                    > **Status:** ${statusPt}
                    > **Rede Total:** ${networkUsage.total}
                    > **Rede Agora:** ${networkUsage.now}\n
                    ** Gerenciamento da aplicação:**`,
                    color: 0x2b2d31
                }],
                components: [{
                    type: 1,
                    components: [
                        {
                            type: 2,
                            label: "▶",
                            style: 3,
                            custom_id: "square-play"
                        },
                        {
                            type: 2,
                            label: "",
                            style: 1,
                            custom_id: "square-restart"
                        },
                        {
                            type: 2,
                            label: "⏹",
                            style: 4,
                            custom_id: "square-stop"
                        },
                        {
                            type: 2,
                            label: "",
                            style: 2,
                            custom_id: "square-logs"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            });
            int.selectedAppId = selectedAppId;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            int.reply({ content: "Ops, algo deu errado. Tente novamente!", ephemeral: true });
        }   
    }
};
```

So when I press the logs button, it returns the log of the correct application of the api:

```
const { ButtonInteraction } = require('discord.js');
const ExtendedClient = require('../../class/ExtendedClient');

const { SquareCloudAPI } = require('@squarecloud/api');
const { squareToken } = require('../../config');

const api = new SquareCloudAPI(squareToken);

module.exports = {
    customId: 'square-logs',
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ExtendedClient} client 
     * @param {ButtonInteraction} int 
     */
    run: async (client, int) => {

    const application = await api.applications.get(appidhere); // In this case, it would have to be the app selected in the selectmenu...
    const logs = await application.getLogs();

    console.log(logs);

    }
};
```

I've tried everything, but it always returns the object with all the apps in the api and not just the id of the one chosen in the selectmenu... I've tried asking for help from chatgpt and other forums and nothing, I couldn't use anything.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).